# loop within loop (php mysql) - when am I killing my server?

Tags: php, mysql, recordset

db looks SOMETHING like this:

```
___________________________________
|id | author     | title          |
___________________________________
|1  | Bob        | Bippety-bop    |
___________________________________
|2  | John       | Doe Tales      |
___________________________________
|3  | Bill       | Lew in the Sky |
___________________________________
|4  | Bob        | More bopping   |
```

I have been trying like mad to do a loop that outputs

```
Bill:
<ul>
<li>Lew in the Sky</li>
</ul>
Bob:
<ul>
<li>Bippety-bop</li>
<li>More bopping</li>
</ul>
John:
<ul>
<li>Doe Tales</li>
</ul>
```

The trick is to sort of group the titles belonging to each author.

I have a working model **but it goes something like this**:

```
$query_rs_distinct = "SELECT DISTINCT author from db_texts ORDER BY author ASC"
...
while ($row_rs_distinct = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_distinct)){
echo $row_rs_distinct['dTTL'];

    $query_rs_all = "SELECT * from db_texts ORDER BY author ASC";
    ....
    do {
        echo '<li>'.$row_rs_all['title'].'</li>';
        } while ($row_rs_all = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_all));

}
```

This gets me a satisfying result but with a large table I may be asking the server to do a new "secondary" query possibly hundreds of times every time I load a page (and at some point some other people will too).

**So my question is - isn't there a better/cleaner way to do this in some while/if-else-looping?** I have tried and spent way more hours (days) than I care to admit - but it just won't give. It seems impossible to me to loop thru all the titles in a secondary loop whithout running back thru the first - OR not being able to close the loop correctly...

Any points are welcome but I could really use some basic help here.

```
Please check this answer and made correction:-


<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);// check all error including warning and notices too
ini_set('display_errors',1); // show the errors
$new_result = array(); // get all data
$conn = mysqli_connect('host name','user name','password','database name') or die(mysqli_connect_error());
if($conn){
    $query_rs_distinct = "SELECT * from db_texts ORDER BY author ASC"; //query to fetch complete record of each author
    $rs_distinct = mysqli_query($conn,$query_rs_distinct)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $i = 0;
    while ($row_rs_distinct = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_distinct)){ 
        $new_result[$row_rs_distinct['author']][] = $row_rs_distinct['title'];
    }
}else{
    echo "database connection error";
}
foreach($new_result as $key=>$result){
    echo $key.'<br/><ul>';
    if(is_array($result)){
        foreach($result as $res){
            echo"<li>".$res."</li>";
        }else{
            echo"<li>".$res."</li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul><br/>";
?>
```

Comment: Do you really want the inner loop to show **all** texts, not just the ones from the author from the current row of the outer loop?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. The first query is just selecting `author`, but you're echoing `dTTL`.

Comment: one query,one loop, is all you need; in the loop you jut need to check when the author changes

Comment: @morganF check my answer i putted in your code. And either it works or not remove them from your question after checking it,.

Comment: @A-2-A. Thanks very much. I can't tell you if your solution works because when I reloaded this page I followed the link at the top (to solved duplicate question) and that worked out for me. So I only realised you left a solution AFTER I have been adjusting the other solution - so in a week with 3 thursdays I'll check up on your suggestion - but for now I have a working version. Thanks again.

Comment: @Barmar - you're very right. Typ-O! Sorry. Should have been $row_rs_distinct['author']; - mishap when I tried to clean up the code for readability. Thanks